# FCM token NotRegistered after unhandled exception in app

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Xamarin forms iOS app set up to work with Firebase Cloud Messaging for push notifications using Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging v3.1.2

I can correctly get an FCM token in the `DidReceiveRegistrationToken` method and then call the REST endpoint `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` and the notification will send as expected.

The issue is, whenever there is an unhandled exception or the current thread is manually killed and my app crashes, the FCM token will then become deregistered and the same API call will result in an `"error": "NotRegistered"` response.

At that point, all I can do is uninstall and reinstall the app to get a new FCM token and things work as expected again.

Here is the main Firebase setup code in my AppDelegate.cs

```cs
       public void RegisterFirebaseNotifications()
        {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;

            var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) =>
            {
                if (error != null)
                {
                    Log.Error("Error occurred getting authorization from user app");
                    Log.Error(error.Description);
                }
            });

            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();

            Messaging.SharedInstance.Delegate = this;

            // To connect with FCM. FCM manages the connection, closing it
            // when your app goes into the background and reopening it
            // whenever the app is foregrounded.
            Messaging.SharedInstance.ShouldEstablishDirectChannel = true;
        }

        #region IMessagingDelegate

        [Export("messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken:")]
        public void DidReceiveRegistrationToken(Messaging messaging, string fcmToken)
        {
            Utils.Settings.FirebaseNotificationToken = fcmToken;
        }

        [Export("messaging:didReceiveMessage:")]
        public void DidReceiveMessage(Messaging messaging, RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
        {
            HandleMessage(remoteMessage.AppData);

            LogInformation(nameof(DidReceiveMessage), remoteMessage.AppData);
        }
        #endregion
```

Comment: Where did you call RegisterFirebaseNotifications?

Comment: Seems there is a discussion in Github and you can have a look at these threads:[issues/2438](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2438#issuecomment-484608515) and [/pull/2860](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/2860). Also try to updated your firebase to the latest version.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT RegisterFirebaseNotifications is called from FinishedLaunching after I call Forms.Init and LoadApplication(new App()). I am reading through the issue and PR now as well

Comment: Yes, that's the right place to call RegisterFirebaseNotifications. Hope you find something form the discussions.

Comment: Those links definitely helped. It seems to be an issue with that version of Firebase Cloud Core/InstanceId. I downgraded to an older version and everything works correctly. Thanks @JackHua-MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue with the version of Firebase Cloud Messaging that I was using. I found [this issue on Github](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/273#issuecomment-504795153) which suggests the versions to downgrade to and that solved my issue.